# sort macro in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use this code to sort a spreadsheet in excel but I am unsure how to put a predefined range in the `.SetRange` property.  I wish to use the `rng1Row` variable I set above.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Set rng1 = wb1.Sheets("SourceData").Cells.Range("A2:A" & N)
Set rng1Row = rng1.EntireRow

wb1.Worksheets("SourceData").Sort.SortFields.Clear
wb1.Worksheets("SourceData").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=wb1.Sheets("SourceData").Cells.Range("A2:A" & N), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
    xlSortNormal
With wb1.Worksheets("SourceData").Sort
    .SetRange
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

Comment: What is your objective? Are you just trying to sort column A?

Answer (score 0):

[Here is the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194114(v=office.15).aspx): **expression .SetRange(Rng)**

`SetRange Range(rng1Row)` (assuming rng1Row is a range)

However, let's look at the first part of your code -

```
N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Set rng1 = wb1.Sheets("SourceData").Cells.Range("A2:A" & N)
Set rng1Row = rng1.EntireRow
```

You are trying to get the row of a column. `rng1Row = (Range("A:A").EntireRow)`. This is not a valid use of the property.