# Use variable as .setrange property

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use this code to sort a spreadsheet in excel but I am unsure how to put a predefined range in the `.SetRange` property.  I wish to use the `rng1Row` variable I set above.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Set rng1 = wb1.Sheets("SourceData").Cells.Range("A2:A" & N)
Set rng1Row = rng1.EntireRow

wb1.Worksheets("SourceData").Sort.SortFields.Clear
wb1.Worksheets("SourceData").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=wb1.Sheets("SourceData").Cells.Range("A2:A" & N), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
    xlSortNormal
With wb1.Worksheets("SourceData").Sort
    .SetRange
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

Comment: Wouldn't `.SetRange rng1Row` work?

Comment: No, It doesn't sort. But it doesn't throw any errors either.

Comment: [relevant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26124236/sort-macro-in-excel/26125944#26125944)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using `.SetRange rng1Row` you are only sorting 1 row.

Change to:

```
.SetRange wb1.Sheets("Source Data").Range("A2").CurrentRegion
```

Or similar to select the entire table of values.